# sql select row from index

Tags: php, mysql, sql

if i had 10 rows which fits this description on mysql

```
SELECT id, nav, img 
FROM mytable 
WHERE id='$id' 
ORDER BY pageDisplayNum ASC;
```

`pageDisplayNum` may not be in numeric order, meaning `1, 2, 5, 10, 16, 22 etc...`
q: how can i choose the 3rd or 6th item from this list
the index number would be coming in from php as a variable
i read about TOP but this didnt work either

```
SELECT TOP $num 
id, nav, img 
FROM mytable 
WHERE id='$id'
ORDER BY pageDisplayNum ASC;
```

Comment: What database are you using?  The best answer is to use the row_number() function, but mysql does not support this function.  Instead you have to use a self-join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This for 7th item

```
SELECT id, nav, img 
FROM mytable 
WHERE id='$id' 
ORDER BY pageDisplayNum ASC;
LIMIT 6,1
```

You can add `LIMIT offset,row_count` query

Comment: You might want to change offset to `5`. `LIMIT 6, 1` will output 7th row, not 6th.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LIMIT <offset>, <#rows>` To select the row you want:

```
SELECT id, nav, img 
FROM mytable 
WHERE id='$id' 
ORDER BY pageDisplayNum ASC
LIMIT 2, 1
```